# Universal APP UserControl: Different XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

Can I add another XAML File to a Windows Universal App UserControl? I want this because the Code is identically, but the structure of the view changes (Image Sizes, Textpositions, and so on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit from a base usercontrol with your common functionality and provide a concrete usercontrol for each set of XAML.  In the code behind of your XAML, you'll simply set the base class to your custom usercontrol.

Comment: Hmm .. sad, but after some attempts and searches i figure out, that this is the only way to go. I have tried to customize via bindings, but my usercontrol has a ListView with DataTemplate and I can't access binding of my UserControl in the DataTemplate. :(